# Flow layout android

Tags: android, flowlayout

As per my understanding, I couldn't find something like iOS Flow Layout in android. I may be wrong, however please let me know if there is any implementation I can use to develop flow layout like feature in Android.

Regards,
Asingh

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean "cover flow"? If you do, have you tried Google at all? Search for "Android cover flow" and the first hit is currently the following:

https://code.google.com/p/android-coverflow/

Comment: No..what i meant was flow layout just like in iOS. For example, if there are multiple control on the screen, say linear layouts, they will be displayed one next to the other one and once the row fills up, the next one will start from next row.